# selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//

Tags: python, html, парсер, selenium

Вываливается такая ошибка при попытке получить XPath селениумом:

> selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="mount_0_0_4s"]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/section/main/div/header/section/div[1]/a/h2"}

Причем текущая страница именно та, которая мне нужна, но категорически ничего не находит на ней.
Думал текущая страница другая. Проверил:

```
current_url = driver.current_url
print("Current URL:", current_url)
```

Страница реально правильная. Код:

```
driver.get(url=url)
time.sleep(5)

driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="mount_0_0_Ae"]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/section/main/div/ul/li[2]/a/span').click()
```

Причем я прохожу страницу авторизации, затем меняю урл на нужный мне. И элементы уже не находит. Любые пробовал.

Comment: ну элемента нет значит, возможно то, что вы в `@id` передаете не такое

Comment: я не по айди ищу а по XPATH.Почему не находит если страница полностью успевает прорисоваться?

Comment: `[@id="mount_0_0_Ae"]` я про это говорю. Зайдите на страницу, которую откроет селениум и найдите этот элемент руками и посмотрите `xpath`

Comment: научным путем выяснил что этот айди постоянно меняется...то есть XPATH постоянно разный.как быть?

Comment: По другим признакам искать, css селекторы, например, я же не знаю, что там за элемент

Comment: привязываюсь к print(driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, '_ac2a _ac2b'))  все равно не находит.Хотя он не меняется и присутствует в 3 экземплярах судя по DOM дереву

Comment: используйте другие локаторы или напишите свой на основе статического объекта